# Snowflake External Stage & PII Data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

We plan to load sensitive PII data from an Azure Blob Storage (ADLS Gen2) into snowflake using an external stage which is secured by Azure credentials ( service principal) for the container where the data is stored.

However this is not an acceptable solution to the cyber team . The use Encryption key was considered. However the key issues that were raised was the the

1. Complete container that stages the PII data could be potentially be exposed.
2. Allowing the Snowflake VNet subnet IDs

Hence I am looking at any best practices or any further suggestions anyone may have that they use when using Azure External Stages to load into Snowflake

Comment: Hi - please can you explain in more detail what/where the issue is? If the data is in an external stage then it is outside of, and not under the control of, Snowflake. Everything inside of Snowflake is encrypted; if that encryption does not satisfy your cyber team then you will need to add your own encryption of these specific fields yourself

Comment: Echoing above, sounds like your issue is with the external stage, not Snowflake.  Have you considered loading into Snowflake directly?  It will be compressed and encrypted upon load, and you can further apply a data masking policy to it to restrict access to data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Complete container that stages the PII data could be potentially be exposed.

You may want to make sure the PII data is encrypted in Azure Blob Storage. Snowflake support ingesting Client-side Encrypted Data into Snowflake. You can read more here:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-encryption-end-to-end.html#ingesting-client-side-encrypted-data-into-snowflake

And this document discussed on how to create a stage with client-side encryption:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html#external-stage-parameters-externalstageparams

2. Allowing the Snowflake VNet subnet IDs

You can add Snowflake VNet subnet IDs to the network rule, restricting access only to the Snowflake VNet subnet IDs, more on this here:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure-allow.html